# Куда делось из греческого русское слово?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Действительно, в западноевропейских языках мы всё больше находим слова, которые, отжив свое прошлое, сегодня заменились синонимами или попросту исчезли.
Однако, вычеркивание ранних слов в западноевропейских языках, лишают нас возможности более-менее полного восстановления тех заимствований из русского языка, которыми успела наполниться Европа в 16-19 вв.

Мы уже приводили, и немало иностранных слов, имеющих в своем составе явно прорусские корни и схожую семантику. Сегодня посмотрим, какую этимологию слову **АЛЫЙ** дает авторитетный этимологический словарь Макса Фасмера. Вот эта статья:

**а́лый**

"ярко-красный", др.-русск. **алъ** в грамотах с XIV в.; см. Корш 8, 647; Срезн. I, 20; укр. **а́лий** – то же. Из тур., крым.-тат. **al** "светло-розовый", тат., кыпч., казах., чагат., уйг. **al** "**алый**" (Mi. TEl. 1, 244; EW 3; Радлов 1, 349 и сл.)

Обратим внимание, что у Фасмера ничего не говорится о параллелях или родственниках в греческом или латинском языках. Запомним это. И зададимся вопросом: "Мог ли знаменитый этимолог упустить, не заметить, что в том же греческом языке есть слово с тем же корнем и с той же семантикой?

Учитывая, что при переводе Словаря с немецкого статьи Фасмера подверглись правке также и группой этимологов во главе с Трубачевым, трудно представить, чтобы все эти специалисты языка могли пропустить столь яркую во всех смыслах русско-греческую пару.

Итак, в греческом находим **άλικος** (**ΑΛΙΚΟΣ**, произносится - **АЛИКОС**) в значение - **АЛЫЙ**.

Вероятно, мы в который раз столкнулись с той "редкостью", о которой не раз говорил и писал доктор филологии **Зализняк**. Вспомним его заверения о том, что русско-итальянская пара **STRANO**-**СТРАННЫЙ** совершенно случайно сложилась в одинаковые графику, фонетику, семантику.

Неужели и теперь, обнаружив **АЛЫЙ** - **АЛИКОС**, мы опять наступили на те же грабли и по неведению приняли эти два ярких слова за родственников?

Подскажите, друзья - есть что-то общее между русским **АЛЫЙ** и греческим **АЛИКОС**?

Или они каким-то чудом совершенно случайно такими получились? Может, нам просто мерещится?

И еще. Как вы думаете, почему этимологические словари не привели греческое **ΑΛΙΚΟΣ** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читайте мой последний коммент насчет вашего "русского" героя. И постарайтесь, наконец, понять, что же такое этимологический словарь. В частности, этимологический словарь *русского языка* (а не греческого и не латинского). Он, этот словарь, вовсе не должен отслеживать путь слова во все-все-все языки — не его это задача. Ну, доступно объяснил? Или будут еще подобные дремучие вопросы?

И ваша "ирония" в адрес ученых-лингвистов совершенно неуместна. Тоже мне, пришел недоучка и "иронизирует".

> > Для очевидных вещей не надо иметь семь пядей во лбу, не сгущайте краски.

Для невежд все вещи — очевидные, Федя. Об этом Чехов хорошо написал.

> > И почему, например, СТРИЖ у Фасмера более уважаем, чем АЛЫЙ: ...  С чего такая избирательность?

Не знаю. Здесь же нет нянек, Федя. Вам интересно — потратьте времени хотя бы вполовину того, что потратил Фасмер. В науке же нет царских путей.

Comment: Странное у Вас рассуждение.

Подумайте, если АЛЫЙ, как выясняется, существовало в греческом, то как можно было обойти его в словаре и написать только, что АЛЫЙ - это древне-русское (АЛЬ  в грамотах с XIV века)слово?

Этимология — раздел лингвистики (сравнительно-историческое языкознание), изучающий происхождение слов, учение об истинном, первоначальном их значении.

Или не так?

Comment: >> Этимология — раздел лингвистики (сравнительно-историческое языкознание), изучающий происхождение слов, учение об истинном, первоначальном их значении.
Или не так?

Врёте, не так. Уберите свою отсебятину (сами знаете, какую) — тогда будет так.

>> как можно было обойти его в словаре и написать только, что АЛЫЙ - это древне-русское (АЛЬ в грамотах с XIV века) слово?

Опять врёте. Насчет "только".

Comment: Niemand, осторожнее.  Я полностью разделяю вашу оценку, но вы подставляетесь под бан за "оскорбление". Поверьте битому.

Comment: Если Вы имеете ввиду "тюрское" AL? так ради Бога, скрыть это невозможно. Любой может проверить.

Однако, это только усугубляет проблему - Фасмер увидел происхождение слова (АЛЫЙ)от турок, но почему-то "не увидел"  от греков. 

Не ищите у меня соринку, смотрите в корень.
Мне, например, непонятно, откуда в Вашем лице такая необходимость оправдывать очевидный ляп этимолога.

Но Вы вполне можете опровергнуть обвинение, если, по примеру Зализняка, докажете, что АЛЫЙ и ΑΛΙΚΟΣ - слова абсолютно независимые.

Никто не мешает Вам сделать это.

Comment: Мало того, если Вы имеете отношение к лингвистике, смогу сослаться на Ваши профессиональные комментарии в своих публикациях.

Comment: >> Фасмер увидел происхождение слова (АЛЫЙ) от турок, но почему-то "не увидел" от греков.

Может, греки тоже заимствовали от турок? Не?

>> Мне, например, непонятно, откуда в Вашем лице такая необходимость оправдывать очевидный ляп этимолога.

Мне, например, непонятно, как это вы, не будучи специалистом, так лихо судите о ляпах, да еще об "очевидных", известнейшего специалиста. Да и других специалистов тоже.

Comment: Вот я не специалист — и я не имею права судить о "ляпах", логично? А вы не специалист — и поэтому вы судите. А теорию относительности можете опровергнуть? Да нисколько не сомневаюсь, что можете. Таков уж ваш брат.

Comment: >> смогу сослаться на Ваши профессиональные комментарии в своих публикациях.

Я прямо так польщен, что кушать не могу ))))))))))

Comment: Не рушьте мир вокруг себя.
Вам трудно сосредоточиться на вопросе?
Для очевидных вещей не надо иметь семь пядей во лбу, не сгущайте краски. 
В любом случае Ваше упорствование в простых вещах вызывает удивление. Зачем?

И почему, например, СТРИЖ у Фасмера более уважаем, чем АЛЫЙ:
... Считают звукоподражательным по происхождению, как греч. στρίγξ, род. п. στριγγός "какая-то ночная птица", лат. strīх, род. п. strigis "ушастая сова"; см. Булаховский, ОЛЯ 7, 119; Преобр. II, 398...
С чего такая избирательность?

Comment: @Федя, а когда в греческом появилось "аликос"? До или после алого в русском?

Answer (score 0):

Innak: "А когда в греческом появилось "АЛИКОС"? До или после АЛОГО в русском?

Отвечаю Вам.

Словарь Фасмера явно упустил греч. АЛИКОС, которое, согласно положению в лингвонауке, было у греков раньше, чем в русском.

Если кто-то из языковедов в этом сомневается, то ему придется засвидетельствовать, что "тюрское" AL и русск.АЛЫЙ каким-то образом появились независимо от греческого АЛИКОС.

Как лингвисты это будут делать нам пока трудно представить.

Нашу точку зрения в отношении приоритета происхождения АЛЫЙ (AL) мы здесь пока не рассматриваем.

Comment: >> Нашу точку зрения...

"Нашу" – это здесь так называемое *"мы" скромности"*? )))))